# How to manage configuration files in microservice architecture among multiple deployment environments?

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration-files

I'm looking for a way to manage configuration files for multiple modules in a large system using microservice architecture (.NET Core).

Currently we have 5 modules and counting. Each module comprises 2 projects (say UI and API). Each project has different configuration for 3 environments Dev, Staging, Production.

5 modules x 2 projects x 3 environments = 30 configuration files.

Many of the projects need the same configuration values repeated verbatim for all development environments (for example where a shared package requires configuration).

Much of the time the same configuration is required for each project and environment, but sometimes it varies and sometimes it is completely project specific.

This is only going to get worse. More modules will be added and the configuration files will get bigger. A solution I'm mulling over is to write a script that does a find and replace in all configuration files based on a master configuration file that has all values for all projects and environments.

But even this seems daunting as I'm not yet sure how I'd layout the master configuration file or make it clear which configuration keys belonged to which projects.

This is becoming very difficult to manage and I'd like to know if anyone has a good process for managing this?

Comment: Do you use a build server/system? If so please say which. Most of them should have a way to deal with this.

Comment: Not currently. Builds are manual, apps are deployed in docker containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common configuration is anathema in microservices architecture. The *entire point* is that they're suppose to be discrete, self-contained units of functionality. If one or more are doing the same thing(s), then you haven't properly subdivided your domain.

The one exception to this is instrumentation: logging, profiling, tracing, etc. If that is what you're talking about here, then there's a number of ways you can handle it.

1. You can have a separate configuration source for your instrumentation, which doesn't even need to be local to the project. For example, you can create a file like `instrumentation.json`, put it in a common shared location, and then in `Program.cs`:

   ```
   CreateDefaultWebBuilder()
       ConfigureAppConfiguration(builderContext, config) =>
       {
           config.AddJsonFile(@"\\path\to\instrumentation.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        })
        .Run();
   ```

   You can even have environment specific JSON for the instrumentation:

   ```
   IHostingEnvironment env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
   config.AddJsonFile($@"\\path\to\instrumentation.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
   ```
2. Docker has its own configuration/secrets setup, which you can use to set environment variables or basically however you want to provide it to the app. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/
3. You can use an distributed configuration source like Azure Key Vault. If you don't want to use that specifically, something like SQL Server or Redis would work just as well, but you'd have to either create custom configuration providers for those or source existing third-party libraries.

Comment: This covers most of my needs. It means that the configuration is local to the application (rather than being remote as with Azure key vault which would prevent offline development). It also means that configuration would be reflected in all apps that the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Try out https://microconfig.io

It is designed exactly for managing microservice configuration with multiple environments.

Comment: But C# uses json configuration and this is more like YAML, how do I use it?

Comment: json is not supported at the moment as output format. can C# work with yaml? usually it's more convenient for large configs.

Comment: It looks like there's an open-source NuGet package from the great Andrew Lock for that (MIT license):
https://github.com/andrewlock/NetEscapades.Configuration#yaml-configuration-provider

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Key Vault acts as your Master Config file.

You will then have a Key Vault for each environment - Dev, Staging, Production.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting service but I don't think it will help with the complexity surrounding multiple projects and deployment environments.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mergeconfigs](https://github.com/x41lakazam/mergeconfigs), it is designed to support merging several configuration files and to facilitate local development.

Comment: It seems that this is your own GitHub account. Please always disclose your affiliation when recommending external resources. Thanks.