# Proper way to pass config to the container during image build

Tags: node.js, docker, microservices, config

I am trying to learn about microservices architecture and docker in general.

I faced an issue of defining config that is shared between `client` and `api` services. I wanted the service image to be configured during the build time.

`api` is made with express.js and `client` is a React app.

The file structure of my project is as follows:

```
project 
└───api
│   │   ...
└───client
│   │   Dockerfile
│   │   .env
│   │   ...
│   docker-compose.yml
│   .env
```

`/.env`:

```
API_URL=localhost
API_PORT=5000
CLIENT_PORT=3000
```

`/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:

  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: production
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 5000:${API_PORT}
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      - API_PORT=${API_PORT}

  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      target: production
      args:
        API_URL: ${API_URL}
        API_PORT: ${API_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/build
    ports:
      - 3000:${CLIENT_PORT}
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      - CLIENT_PORT=${CLIENT_PORT}
```

`/client/.env`:

```
REACT_APP_CLIENT_LOGIN=admin
REACT_APP_CLIENT_PASSWORD=123
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57711655/12175087) answer, which made me understand why I should move some of my `client`-specific config into the `client/.env`, which I already did. But still, I find `API_PORT` and `API_URL` variables are supposed to be shared between `api`(to decide which port to listen) and `client`(to define full url to send requests to) services. I also moved `CLIENT_PORT` to the `/.env` as well, in order to not handle it's value in both `client/Dockerfile`(for defining at which port to listen to) and `docker-compose.yml`(for port forwarding to host port).

The only way I could make `API_URL` and `API_PORT` accessible in both `development` and `production` at the build time is as follows:

`/client/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14 as base
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./

ARG API_URL
ARG API_PORT

# here goes ugly solution part
RUN echo "\n" >> .env
RUN echo "REACT_APP_API_URL=$API_URL" >> .env
RUN echo "\n" >> .env
RUN echo "REACT_APP_API_PORT=$API_PORT" >> .env
RUN echo "\n" >> .env

FROM base as development
CMD [ "npm","start" ]

FROM base as production
RUN npm install -g serve
RUN npm run build
CMD ["sh", "-c", "serve -n -s build -l $CLIENT_PORT"]
```

The solution works but obviously is weird to say the least. I wonder if there's better solution to this situation? Maybe, more "docker", "react" or "microservices" way to do it?

**Edit**: since the comment of Andreas Jagiella, I need to clarify that I stored credentials in `/client/.env` just for mocking authentication check. I wouldn't use them like that in a real project.

Comment: The system should only read from `.env`, never write to it. The file is ment to be populated by the developer's hands, not by Dockerfile.

Comment: First of all, storing login credentials in the client env is similar to having no login at all since you can just read it on the client side. 
Also setting your API_PORT inside the server makes no sense since it will always be mapped to port 5000 on the host (this is the port that your client has to connect to). So just remove it? API_URL also must be the url of your host.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andreas Jagiella, I can conclude that I was confused with basic concepts of networking in docker.

`API_PORT` and `CLIENT_PORT` were substituted to `5000` and `3000` (which, as I understood, didn't matter as long as they mapped correspondingly) in `docker-compose.yml`. `API_URL` is now in `/client/.env` and is `localhost:5000`. The root `/.env` file was deleted due to its uselessness. Writing to `/client/.env` instructions were deleted from `/client/Dockerfile`.

Everything still works, and now it looks okay, especially since I don't have to violate "runtime read-only" idea of `.env` file, which I learned from Daniel W.'s comment.

So, I guess my conclusion is that:

1. there is no need in specifying ports when ports forwarding is used
2. domain part of `API_URL` is constantly `localhost` when deployed under the same network